# Which of these two functions has a higher order of growth/complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Consider the following functions:

$$f(n)=2^{\log^*n} \text{ and } g(n)=\sqrt{2}^{\log{n}}$$

Using $\log{}$ properties I think that $g(n) < f(n)$, since:

1. $f(n)\sim n$,
2. $g(n)\sim n^{\frac{1}{2}}$, and
3. $n^{\frac{1}{2}}<n$.

However the book that I'm reading says otherwise.

What have I gotten wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have gotten wrong the 1st property, that $2^{\log^*(n)} \sim ~n$.  This is not the case.

The notation [$\log^*(n)$ is the *iterated logarithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm), and the iterated logarithm grows much much slower than the logarithm, so $f$ grows much slower than linearly.

Comment: I'm aware of the definition of log star, so I guess the question is don't log* and log have the same properties? because if they do then I can do this: $2^{log^*n}=n^{log^*2}=n^1=n$.

Comment: No, $2^{\log^* 100} \sim 8$, whereas $100^{\log^* 2} \sim 100$.